# Can you Run Java on Chrome? JNLP?

Tags: google-chrome, jnlp, tightvnc-jviewer

I am making a website, and I NEED to have a VNC Viewer on it. I already use Tight VNC and they have a Java Viewer. This code is able to run as an applet, but modern browsers such as Chrome and Firefox do not allow applets. Is there another way to run Java code on Chrome?

I have read that some browsers support Java Web Start, but I don't think Chrome does. If Chrome does can anyone help me convert this applet to a JNLP file?

```
<applet archive="tightvnc-jviewer.jar"
    code="com.glavsoft.viewer.Viewer"
    width="1" height="1">
    <param name="Host" value="localhost"/>
    <!-- Host to connect. Default:  the host from which the applet was loaded. -->
    <param name="Port" value="5900"/>
    <!-- Port number to connect. Default: 5900 -->
    <!--param name="Password" value="" /--> <!-- Password to the server (not recommended to use this parameter here) -->
    <param name="OpenNewWindow" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="ShowControls" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="ViewOnly" value="no"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: no/false -->
    <param name="AllowClipboardTransfer" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="RemoteCharset" value="standard"/>
    <!-- Charset encoding is used on remote system. Use this option to specify character encoding will be used for encoding clipboard text content to. Default value (when parameter is empty): local system default character encoding. Set the value to 'standard' for using 'Latin-1' charset which is only specified by rfb standard for clipboard transfers. -->

    <param name="ShareDesktop" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="AllowCopyRect" value="yes"/>
    <!-- yes/true or no/false. Default: yes/true -->
    <param name="Encoding" value="Tight"/>
    <!-- Possible values: "Tight", "Hextile", "ZRLE", and "Raw". Default: Tight -->
    <param name="CompressionLevel" value=""/>
    <!-- 1-9 or empty. Empty means server default -->
    <param name="JpegImageQuality" value=""/>
    <!-- 1-9, Lossless or empty. When param is set to "Lossless" no jpeg compression used. Empty means server default -->
    <param name="LocalPointer" value="On"/>
    <!-- Possible values: on/yes/true (draw pointer locally), off/no/false (let server draw pointer), hide). Default: "On"-->
    <param name="ConvertToASCII" value="no"/>
    <!-- Whether to convert keyboard input to ASCII ignoring locale. Possible values: yes/true, no/false). Default: "No"-->

    <param name="Tunneling" value="auto"/>
    <!-- Tunneling. Possible values:
    auto - allow viewer to choose tunneling mode,
    none/no - no tunneling use,
    SSL - choose SSL tunneling when available.
    Default: "auto" -->

    <param name="colorDepth" value=""/>
    <!-- Reserved for future. Possible values: 6, 8, 16, 24, 32 (equals to 24). Only 24/32 is supported now -->
    <param name="ScalingFactor" value="100"/>
    <!-- Scale local representation of the remote desktop on startup. Default is 100 means 100% -->
    <!--param name="showConnectionDialog" value="yes" /-->
    <!-- Set to "No" if you want not to show initial connection dialog. Default: "Yes". -->
    <param name="AppletGoodbyeURL" value="about:blank"/>
    <!-- URL to be redirected on applet stopping. When blank or absent stop applet and do nothing. -->
    <!-- SSH tunneling options -->
    <param name="sshHost" value=""/>
    <!-- SSH host name. -->
    <param name="sshUser" value=""/>
    <!-- SSH port number. When empty, standard SSH port number (22) is used -->
    <param name="sshPort" value=""/>
    <!-- SSH user name. -->

</applet>
```

If you want the .jar file it is downloadable at http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php

If there is no way to run Java from Chrome, is there a way for me to make a link that will open the user to that page in Internet Explorer?

Comment: https://github.com/novnc/noVNC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox dropped Java support a while ago. Edge didn't support it to begin with. You can open .jnlp files from every browser (see the example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/examplesIndex.html)) but it is like opening any executable file you download from the internet somewhere. Check out the above example and see how it behaves in each of those browsers.

> If there is no way to run Java from Chrome, is there a way for me to make a link that will open the user to that page in Internet Explorer?

No you can't switch the browser. That would be a great security risk and what would you do on macOS or linux?

Regarding the migration to webstart *racle provides some support [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet_migration.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/migrating-java-applets-jnlp.htm#JSDPG-GUID-09C10AD7-8B69-445D-81DD-C3F2C531248C).

Comment: When I run the example in chrome it downloads a file that you have to open. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: No unfortunatly not. Additionally if a user doesn't have Java installed on his system he cannot open it...

Answer (score 0):

Neither Chrome nor Firefox support Java applets. You must switch to HTML5 or flash.